# List all GCP projects in an org with a service enabled with gcloud/Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to figure out how to use `gcloud`/Cloud Shell to list out all projects in an organization where BigQuery (or any service/API) is enabled. I know I can use `gcloud projects list --filter` to list all projects that meet a filter criteria but it's not clear to me how to use the [filter option](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters). The article says to print out an example project as YAML to find the filter criteria but it didn't list out the APIs I know the project has enabled.

Is there a way to get this with `projects list`, or even just a one-liner? I know I can get it with `gcloud services list --enabled --project` but I was really hoping to not have to write a big script for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use asset inventory API. See below usage and link to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/list-services#org-list-enabled)

Replace the `ORGANIZATION_ID` and `BILLING_PROJECT_ID` with your values

Hope this helps

```
NOW=$(TZ=GMT date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
gcloud asset list \
--organization='ORGANIZATION_ID' \
--billing-project='BILLING_PROJECT_ID' \
--asset-types='serviceusage.googleapis.com/Service' \
--snapshot-time=$NOW \
--content-type='resource'
```